# hg-git push silently fails

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

I'm trying to use `hg push` to a git repository, but it silently fails.  I found [a single post on the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/hg-git/browse_thread/thread/8ec99bad0fc59c6c) and [a registered hg-git issue](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/211), but both are about half a year old without much activity.  So I started to think I misunderstand/misconfigure something.
My `~/.hgrc` contains

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hgext.git =
#hggit = /path/to/hg-git-0.3.1/hggit
[bookmarks]
track.current = True
```

This snippet reproduces the problem:

```
mkdir /tmp/Git
cd /tmp/Git
git init
echo 'something' > myfile
git add .
git commit -m 'Started'
cd ..
hg clone /tmp/Git /tmp/Hg
cd /tmp/Hg
echo 'another thing' >> myfile
hg ci -m 'Working'
hg log
# Two items listed
hg push
cd ../Git
git log
# Only one item listed, but two expected
```

I tried both `hg-git 0.2.6-2` shipped with Ubuntu 11.10, and the latest tagged version, `0.3.1`.  My mercurial is version 1.9.1

I even tried two proposed workarounds, `hg update master` before commiting, and `hg bookmark -f master` after commiting, but both gave an error.

UPDATE:

I created a [new issue for this](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/issue/30)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two issues here: push should explicitly fail, and hg-git should report it (but it doesn't).

Pushing should fail, giving `"abort: git remote error: refs/heads/master failed to update" when pushing to local clone`, because it's a push to a non-bare repository (see [more on that from a mercurial user's perspective](http://www.bitflop.com/document/111)).  A working version of the above snippet is this (note the use of the `Bare` repository).

```
mkdir /tmp/Git
cd /tmp/Git
git init
echo 'something' > myfile
git add .
git commit -m 'Started'
cd ..
git clone --bare -l /tmp/Git /tmp/Bare
hg clone /tmp/Bare/ /tmp/Hg
cd /tmp/Hg
echo 'another thing' >> myfile
hg ci -m 'Working'
hg log
# Two items listed
hg push
cd ../Bare
git log
# Two items listed
```

Regarding, why `hg-git` hides this error, I suspect it's a problem with the most recent versions shipped with Ubuntu.  What I did was

```
apt-get remove mercurial-git python-dulwich
easy_install hg-git
```

It removed `dulwich 0.7.1`, and installed `0.8` which is required according to the `hg-git` site.  Now, it works for me.  The mercurial version (`1.9.1`) seems to work fine.